# Joda DateTime in OrientDB Object API

Tags: java, orientdb

I am using JDK 8, JodaTime 2.9.9 and OrientDB version 2.2.26.

Is there a way to use DateTime objects with OrientDB Object API?

Example class:

```
class Entity {

    private DateTime date;

    public Entity(DateTime date){
        this.date = date
    }

    public DateTime getDate(){
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(DateTime newDate){
        this.date = newDate;
    }
}
```

Registering in OrientDB:

```
database.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(Entity)
```

If I try to save it:

```
database.save(new Entity(DateTime.now()))
```

Then I get:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: 
Linked type [class org.joda.time.DateTime:2017–09–12T11:50:25.709–03:00] 
cannot be serialized because is not part of registered entities.
```

If I try to register DateTime:

```
database.getEntityManager().registerEntityClass(DateTime)
```

And I try to save entity again:

```
database.save(new Entity(DateTime.now()))
```

Since it is a final class, javassist cannot proxy it, so I got a:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.joda.time.DateTime is final
```

I don’t wanna to change my class to store a long instead of a DateTime. Is there a way to implement and register some sort of serializer and deserializer for DateTime or something that, similarly, would not interfere with my entity?

Comment: Hi, which version are you using and can you post the code? Thx

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi Done, hope it helps! I was unsure which versions you were referering to, so I added the JDK and Joda time versions, OrientDB version was already in the original post.

Comment: Just curious: why are you using Joda Time and not the Date/Time API from Java8? From their site: Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

Comment: @MystyxMac I was using Java 7 with joda, then I changed to Java 8 and I didn't want to migrate to java.time since I see no reason to do so. Perhaps when building a new application I will give a try with the new java.time API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find out how to do it (code in Groovy):

```
    def orientDbServer = OServerMain.create()
    System.setProperty("ORIENTDB_HOME", new File("").getAbsolutePath());
    orientDbServer.startup(new OServerConfiguration().with { cfg ->
        location = "memory"
        network = new OServerNetworkConfiguration(this)
        users = [new OServerUserConfiguration(name: "root", 
                                              password: "root",
                                              resources: "*")] as OServerUserConfiguration[]
        cfg
    })
    orientDbServer.activate()

    addShutdownHook {
        orientDbServer.shutdown()
    }

    new OServerAdmin("localhost").connect("root", "root")
                                 .createDatabase("test", "document", "memory").close()
    OObjectDatabaseTx database = 
                    new OObjectDatabaseTx("memory:localhost/test").open("admin", "admin")

    OObjectSerializerContext serializerContext = new OObjectSerializerContext();
    serializerContext.bind(new OObjectSerializer<DateTime, Long>() {
        @Override
        Object serializeFieldValue(Class<?> iClass, DateTime iFieldValue) {
            return iFieldValue.getMillis()
        }

        @Override
        Object unserializeFieldValue(Class<?> iClass, Long iFieldValue) {
            return new DateTime(iFieldValue)
        }
    }, database)

    OObjectSerializerHelper.bindSerializerContext(null, serializerContext)
```

It is important that the serializerContext is registered before any entity class registration